# my input from "Scanner" is not being recorded? Returns nothing

Tags: java

I am making a small project for computer science. I am making a code to test if a string input is a palindrome, or a phrase that is the same forward and backwards, Ex. "racecar" = "racecar" when read backwards.

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a palindrome or something...: ");
        String myLine = keyboard.nextLine();
        Palindrome test = new Palindrome();
        test.setPaly(myLine);
        System.out.println(test);
```

my scanner goes into a variable 'myLine' which I throw into my other piece of code in another file, called by a toString through `System.out.println(test)`from the last block of code:

```
public void setPaly(String setp)
    {
        in = setp;
        boolean b1 = true;
        int x = 0;
        while(x<in.length())
        {
            b1 = Character.isLetter(x);
            if (b1 != false)
            {
                paly = paly + in.substring(x, x+1);
            }
            x++;
        }
    }
```

see, 'paly' and 'in' are both pre-initialized, but that isn't my problem... my question comes here: *'paly' never actually get overwritten.* Why is this? I don't understand at all... so please explain a little more thoroughly than just giving me an answer.

I am using codeboard.io to make this, and as such, you can look at my full code (in case It actually isn't part of these chunks of code at all) here: 
Link: (https://codeboard.io/projects/33278?view=21.1-2.0)

Comment: If you want `setPaly()` to decide if an input be a palindrome, then you should return a `boolean` response, rather than keeping it `void`.  Also, I don't see where `in` is being initialized.

Comment: Add some temporary system.out.prints in and around that loop so you can trace the value of in, x, paly, etc. This is a good and simple debugging technique. It will shed light on what's going on.

Comment: `Character.isLetter(x);` ... you might want to remember what `x` ***really*** is ... hint: not a letter. (at least not for short Strings)

Comment: @Tim in = setp is up on the first line of that function, fyi.

Comment: Here is a list of ways to check for palindrome: [Check string for palindrome](//stackoverflow.com/q/4138827)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very simple problem, perhaps even a simple typo.
Your line

```
b1 = Character.isLetter(x)
```

is, I presume, attempting to check if the value at **x** in the string is a character. 
However, it does *not* do that, for a few reasons.

---

**x** is an int. If we check the docs we find the following:

```
isLetter(int codePoint)
Determines if the specified character (Unicode code point) is a letter.
```

When you pass isLetter the int (**x**, which will count from 0 to some reasonably low value), it simply checks if those code points are letters. The first Unicode letter is at U+0041, and indeed if you enter a sting longer than 41 characters into your program, it'll start returning values.

I imagine what you are looking for is

```
b1 = Character.isLetter(in.charAt(x));
```

This is a simple conflation of index values with values at an index, a problem that would be *normally* caught precompile, but isn't because of the extra methods of isLetter.

Because it never returns as the codepoint being a letter (until you get past the initial control characters and gubbins), the condition is simply never true, and thus doesn't modify **paly**.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem isn't the logic, but what you are checking.

```
        // ....
        while(x<in.length())
        {
            // This is actually checking the number stored in x
            // a number is never a letter
            b1 = Character.isLetter(x);
            // ....         
        }
```

You should be asking for the char in the setp and checking that value instead
Try doing

```
b1 = Character.isLetter(setp.charAt(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

My second body of code (that I posted) is the location of the source my problem. I had been trying to reference `int x` but in fact I meant to do something like `in.charAt(x)`, which would reference the character in the location of x in the input, which in was set to equal.